# Need date range between two columns

Tags: date, range

I need all the hours and minutes in between two dates. I have a column for the day and a column with hours and minutes.  `WHERE (cast([MY_TIME] as date) >= '20160501' and CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [MY_TIME], 108) >= '23:15')
or (cast([My_TIME] as date) <= '20160502' and CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), [My_TIME], 108) <= '02:45')`  I had to break up the datetime column to get the date in one column and the hours and minutes in another and take out the seconds. Instead of getting all the hours and minutes in between, I get 02:45 to 23:15 for one day, which is not what I need.  How should I write this instead.

Comment: MySQL?  SQL Server?  Postgres?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.